# Updating child record from Parent using Web Service

Tags: apex, soap-api, webservices, update, partner-wsdl

I have shared my org's salesforce partner wsdl to an external system. I send a request to them using SOAP callout and in the request I send the ID of a parent Sobject.

Now the external system makes an inbound call to update some records in Salesforce using partner WSDL. They only have the parent ID with them using which they will call the update service. Is it possible for the external system to use this parent ID and update the child records of the parent ? If Not is there a way to do this?

Comment: Update all of them? Or just some? It would be easy to expose a `webservice` to do what you need.

Comment: Update some of the child record of that parent. If I need to expose a webservice how do I do it? By creating apex class and exposing as REST? If I need to use SOAP service is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [`webservice`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services_methods.htm) here, which can be called via SOAP.

```
global with sharing class MyWebService
{
    webservice static void updateChildren(Id parentId)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

You'll need to generate a new WSDL once you add this Web Service so it can be called.

Comment: Thanks. Would I be generating partner WSDL or enterprise wsdl for this? Or is there any other way to generate the wsdl?

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter [if you use Enterprise or Partner WSDL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_generate_wsdl.htm). You should also have a read of [Considerations for Using the `WebService` Keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services_methods_considerations.htm).

Comment: If I happen to add one more operation in apex web service class, then I do have to generate the wsdl again and send it to the external system right? I read somewhere the difference between partner and enterprise wsdl , we don't need to send the updated partner wsdl again to external system in case of a change on salesforce side but if it is enterprise wsdl then we have to send the updates wsdl again to the external system for them to consume the updated service

Comment: I'm not very familiar with that aspect. If you have more detailed questions in that regard, I suggest a separate question.